# Watchdog in Python to look for filesystem changes not working (freezing)

Tags: python-3.x, python-watchdog

I'm working on a Python script to monitor a folder to check whether a new *.JPG file is added to that folder and then do some tasks. The code is working, but after some time after being started, it seems to be freezing and stops working even a new file is added to the folder.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- encoding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import time
import os
import flickrapi
import shutil
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = ["*.jpg"]
    ignore_patterns = None
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = False
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

def get_exif(img):
    ''' Extract Exif data from image '''

def copyright(img):
    # get the path of img and create an output filename
    tail = os.path.split(img)[1]
    filename = 'wtmk_' + tail[:-3] + 'png'

    #open the base image and get it's dimensions
    while True:
        try:
            # read file
            base_image = Image.open(img)
            bw, bh = base_image.size
            bw2 = bw // 2
            break
        except IOError:
            time.sleep(5)
            
       ''' Add watermark to image '''
    
    return waterMarkedImage

def on_created(event):
    # Add the watermark
    file = copyright(event.src_path)

    # extract EXIF data
    exifdata = get_exif(event.src_path)
 
    ''' Send the image to FLICKR '''

# Create and start the observer
my_event_handler.on_created = on_created

path = "c:\\temp"
go_recursively = False
my_observer = Observer()
my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)
my_observer.start()

try:
    while True:
            time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
```

I'm running the above code using Python 3.8 on a Windows 10 machine. Any help would be awesome!

Marcio

Comment: i don't know enough about PIL to give a full answer, but you should close the image file after opening when you're done with it, `base_image.close()`

Comment: Hi @Shameen. Yes, I do close both base_image and watermark image before returning the watermarked image from the function. I cut the code because it was long and cannot be posted, but here it is:     # Close opened images  base_image.close() watermark.close()

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an issue with your cmd.exe
To fix the script freezing open your cmd, click on your cmd icon in the top left, then go to Defaults and uncheck the QuickEdit Mode.
Then restart cmd and start your script. Hope that helps!